# One of my tables isn't shown in the model diagram EF5.0 VS 2013 Community

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework

[Model Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HpMQ.jpg)

Hi all! Noobie here, I am using VS 2013 community edition to build an inventory control application and also using Entity Framework 5.0. I have used the database first approach to create the above model.

If i describe the model i have a user table which i have used to save login information. And there are three tables which are customers, transactions and products. Transaction table has a foreign key relationship with customer table where i map a customerid for a transaction. And i also have another table which is called transprods where it stores the information of which items being sold by a transaction. Where it only consists of two columns both are foreign keys which are transaction_id and product_id. How ever this particular table isn't getting generated in the diagram and also it doesn't generate code. What is the cause for this?! but in the model browser i do see the **transprod** inside the table directory. What i am doing wrong here any help would be greatly appreciated. And also my database is mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "by design"

When you have a table that contains only foreign keys to two other tables, it will show up in the model as a many-to-many relationship between these two other tables.

If you add an extra field to this connector table, for example created date, then it will show up in the model as a separate table.

Comment: Thanks! i was thinking about it whether it will make any difference if i add a column! Finally i was able to get desired outcome using the above model!